# plotly, not showing coordinates with np.array dataset

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, data-visualization, plotly

I wish to display a dataset of 1000 float, I have decided to do this with plotly, and I want to do it offline, I am getting in to a problem I really can't understand - I simply don't know what I am doing wrong at all.

Let's jump in to the code. First of I will show that the code should work, with a small np.array

```
import numpy as np
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

list = [1.2,2.3,3.3,4.4,5.4,6.4] 
x_data = np.array(list)
y_data = np.array(list)

#x_data = np.array(graph_test_q())
#y_data = np.array(graph_test_h())

trace = go.Scatter(
   x = x_data,
   y = y_data,
)

data = [trace]
fig = dict(data=data)
py.offline.plot(fig, filename='hejsa.html')
print data
```

The output of the above code:
[image: Output of small np.array]
Seems to work fine, but:
Below is the code, where I use a np.array created from a function, that extracts it from a postgrSQL db. I have checked, and it does print the data in the terminal.

```
def graph_test_q():
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='database1' user='postgres'        password='FFgg1905560' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur  = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT q FROM pump_data_test WHERE pump_id = 1229")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return rows

def graph_test_h():
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='database1' user='postgres'    password='FFgg1905560' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur  = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT h FROM pump_data_test WHERE pump_id = 1229")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return rows

#list = [1.2,2.3,3.3,4.4,5.4,6.4]
#x_data = np.array(list)
#y_data = np.array(list)

x_data = np.array(graph_test_q())
y_data = np.array(graph_test_h())

trace = go.Scatter(
    x = x_data,
    y = y_data,
)

data = [trace]
fig = dict(data=data)
py.offline.plot(fig, filename='hejsa.html')
print data
```

Now here is what I find strange, the output of these new np.arrays is this empty graph:
[image]

When I click on the link in the bottom right corner - "export to plot.ly" this is now the output I get:
[image]
Here I can see see the graph on the left, just as it's supposed to be. I would be very appreciated if anyone can help me find out what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:
From comments: Code for showing dtypes of x_data & y_data ( x_data = np.array(graph_test_q()) & y_data = np.array(graph_test_h())):

```
print(x_data.dtype)
print(y_data.dtype)
```

output:

float64

float64

0:96: execution error: "file://hejsa.html" doesn’t understand the “open location” message. (-1708)

70:78: execution error: Can’t get application "firefox". (-1728)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: Can you add the output of `print(x_data.dtype)`? I suspect you get back an array of strings and numbers which confuses Plotly.

Comment: yes ofc. edit inc

Comment: It seems to be the same dtype

Comment: Sorry, wrong track, I think I found your problem, have a look at the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchall` returns tuples, so you end up with a `Numpy` array which has a shape of `(n, 1)` where n is the number of results. You could get the data in the correct format for `Plotly` using the following index:

```
np.array(graph_test_q())[:,0]
```

See below for a complete demo.

```
import plotly
import numpy as np
import random
import sqlite3

def graph_test_q():
    cur  = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT q FROM pump_data_test WHERE pump_id = 1229")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows

def graph_test_h():
    cur  = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT h FROM pump_data_test WHERE pump_id = 1229")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

# Create some mockup data
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE pump_data_test (h, q, pump_id)")
for i in range(10):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO pump_data_test VALUES ('{}','{}',1229)".format(i, i + random.random()))
conn.commit()

trace1 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
    name='works',
    x=np.array(graph_test_q())[:,0],
    y=np.array(graph_test_h())[:,0],
)
trace2 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
    name='does not work',
    x=np.array(graph_test_q()),
    y=np.array(graph_test_h()),
)

data = [trace1, trace2]
fig = dict(data=data)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: It gives the `0` index: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html